# Change directory command in Docker on Windows is not working

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have docker that runs the following file:

```
CMD /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
```

First command in the deploy.sh file is

```
cd /home/app
```

It works in Docker on Linux, however in Docker on Windows I have following error:

```
 /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /home/app
```

What is the reason?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
RUN apt-get update
RUN npm install pm2 -g
WORKDIR /home/app
ADD ./deploy.sh /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
RUN chmod g+x /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
CMD /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh
```

Comment: I bet that the problem is with Windows-style line endings: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154411/297621

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `CRLF (Windows)` line ending and don't `LF (linux)`  that is required for running .sh or working in linux in general (docker -> linux).

Open the `deploy.sh` file in notepad++ or IntelIJ IDE (I'm primary always working in InteljIJ with docker on Windows) and check line-ending.

I'm always using LF ending globaly for evry project with IntelIJ on Windows.

Comment: I have converted line ending to LF and still there is the same problem.

Comment: Try add `RUN tr -d '\r' < /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh > /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh` command to your Dockerfile before CMD, it still looks like crlf problem

Comment: I have added this after `ADD ./deploy.sh /usr/local/bin/deploy.sh` line and still the same :(